# Kill Missing form variable in Session, and redefine it

Tags: coldfusion

The Form variable in my form is being passed/retrieved via Session.

I have a troublesome Form variable(`formField1`) that was NOT DEFINED properly in the Session, but the whole form was put into use. Then this particular Form variable(formField1) was filled and used, trapping it in the Session and throwing an error. I gave a stop gap solution:

```
 <cfif isDefined("TTsession.filing.formField1")>
       <cfset TTD formField1 = TTsession.filing.formField1>
     <cfelse>
       <cfset TTD formField1 = "0">
     </cfif>
```

> `TTsession`= name of the Session variable
>   `formField1`= name of the erroneous form field.

As a result of which all the forms in which `TTsession.filing.formField1` was improperly defined are giving an output of `0`.

I do not want this. What I want to do is:

1. Check Does form variable EXIST in session?
2. If yes,

   ```
   <cfset FormVar1=session.FormVar1>
   ```
3. If no,

   1. KILL THE MISSING form variable in that Session.

      re-Define the form variable FormVar1 right here in that Session.

      ```
      <cfset FormVar1=session.FormVar1>
      ```

I am using CFMX6.1.

Comment: @Rames: On an unrelated note - please also have a look at the answers to your other questions and check if some of them deserve to be accepted. It's considered fair around here to up-vote and accept working answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfparam name="FormVar1" default="0">

<!--- set overide defaults if in the session --->
<cfif StructKeyExists( TTsession.filing, "formField1")>
   <cfset FormVar1 = TTsession.filing.formField1>
</cfif>
```

I think the problem might be where you have created this session, however if you merely want to set defaults just use cfparam :

```
 <cfparam name="session.filling.formfield1" type="numeric" default="0">
```

So if the session var is defined, do nothing.  Else define it with the value of zero.  All in one line.

Comment: thanks "ethyreal".But I really want to tell it "if form variable is undefined  in the session" DEFINE it right now.

How to do this?

Comment: cfparam will define an undefined value, but not overwrite a defined one.

Comment: Ben my worry is that those forms in which the formField1 is undefined in "Session" , are unable to EDIT /SAVE their forms...of course this needs a lengthy look at the code...
what I want to Provide A condition that EVEN IF "formField1 " IS UNDEFINED IN THE "Session" (which an user used while SAVING the form some time ago),DEFINE IT NOW!

Comment: @Rames unless I'm missing something you just described cfparam's entire function.  If this is not the case please provide more information or update your question.